# OpenCV on Jetson TK1 is much slower than custom Cuda code

Tags: opencv, cuda

I'm developing an OpenCV application on the Jetson TK1. I'm using the OpenCV4Tegra package provided by NVIDIA.

dpkg -l output:

```
ii  libopencv4tegra                                       2.4.10.1                                            armhf        OpenCV4Tegra
ii  libopencv4tegra-dev                                   2.4.10.1                                            armhf        OpenCV4Tegra
ii  libopencv4tegra-repo                                  2.4.10.1                                            armhf        OpenCV4Tegra
```

I'm trying to get an idea of the speedup the Jetson can provide for my application.

I've tested copying data from the host to the device.

OpenCV code:

```
cv::Mat src_host = cv::imread("image.png");
cv::gpu::GpuMat src;
src.upload(src_host);
```

I've placed the upload call in a loop and timed it. It usually averages to about 10ms.

When I try similar Cuda code:

```
cv::Mat src_host = cv::imread("image.png");
int nb_bytes = src_host.rows*src_host.cols*src_host.elemSize1();
uchar* data;
cudaMalloc(&data, nb_bytes);
cudaMemcpy(data, src_host.data, nb_bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

This code averages to about 50-100us.

When I try OpenCV operations like:

```
cv::gpu::GaussianBlur(src, dst, cv::Size(25, 25), 0);
```

This also takes an order of a magnitude longer than a custom Cuda implementation.

Am I using OpenCV's gpu functions incorrectly? Am I making incorrect assumptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you launch your code using nvvp you will see that opencv call a cudaDeviceSynchronize after each operation you can do on your device.

To avoid these synchronization you must use their asynchronous API by creating a gpu::Stream and launch your operations into the stream.

Don't forget to put one synchronize after all your kernels calls.

You can also note that for some operations (erode/dilate/GaussianBlur/...) the first call is during much time than the others, to avoid that you can call them a once during your device initialization in order to benchmark your code correctly just after.